# NMap only works in --unprivilged mode?

Tags: ethernet

This question originated from an earlier NMap question [here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20265/nmap-failed-to-open-device-eth1). Anyways, my NMap will only work inside --unprivileged mode. How can I make NMap operate outside --unprivileged? The same thing persist across Cygwin, ZenMap,and NMap CMD. Information about --iflist, versions, adapters, ect. can be found at the original question.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use command line and Run with administrator account and type --privilege to run in privilege mode.

Ex: `nmap --privilege -sP 10.x.x.x`